# Search Wordpress pages by adding keywords

Tags: wordpress

I have a site set up that only uses pages (no blog posts). Is there a way to add keywords/tags to each page and then have a search plugin that searches these keywords/tags?

So if I have a page called "handyman services" I would like to add keywords/tags to that page similar to "handyman, carpenter, handy" and then be able to search for "carpenter" and get a hit, even if that page doesn't contain that word in the actual text (just in the keyword/tag)?

Might be a basic questions but the search plugins I look at are focused on blog posts mainly.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/tag-pages/

Comment: Thanks mevius! Looks like something interesting. SHould I use a search plugin if I only want the search function to search these tags instead of the default way? I'm quite new to this so modifying the code is not something I would like to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a SEO plugin like this one: [YOAST](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/)